# Babun or Cygwin with Meteor

Tags: windows, meteor, cygwin, babun

Opening a normal *cmd* prompt on Windows and typing:

> meteor

Will work correctly. But won't work in Cygwin (or Babun):

> zsh: command not found: meteor

How to make it work ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Adding an alias works like a charm:

```
alias meteor="meteor.bat"
```